# Gradle task pmdMain can not be found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to run the pmdMain task from gradle v2.7.

In my build.gradle file, I have this code after I reference the maven repo:

```
apply plugin: 'pmd'
```

And the error that occurs when I run the task:

```
./gradlew pmdMain

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Task 'pmdMain' not found in root project
```

Comment: check [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/issues-with-m8s-pmd-plugin/6441) and [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/pmd-ruleset-not-available-in-classpath/7201) link